# MYSQL Query: ORDER BY specific date

Tags: mysql, date, sql-order-by

I am currently creating a website on which I can add videos. When I add a video, I need to give a release date, formatted like: "21-09-2012".

Now, when I use the simple ORDER BY command, it only sorts on the first two digits.

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: what is the datatype of your release date field?

Comment: Is the column for the release-date field a `date` data-type, or something else such as `varchar`?

Comment: Don't use a string format to store a date. Use [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html?ff=nopfpls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are storing your date field as a string instead.  If that it the case then you will need to convert the value to a date before trying to order it:

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(yourdate, '%d-%m-%Y')
FROM    yourtable
```

MySQL documentation on [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

However, you should be storing your dates in a date datatype and not as a string value. Then you will not have to perform these types of conversions.

You can also do the conversion in the ORDER BY statement itself:

```
order by STR_TO_DATE(yourdate, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: @ClintonWard true, they should be storing the date in a date datatype but if they want to convert this is how to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

After very boring research, I had a brilliant idea:

Format: `18/11/2014`

```
select id,
       date_string,
       substr(date_string, 1, 2) as day,
       substr(date_string, 4, 2) as month,
       substr(date_string, 7, 4) as year
from myTable
order by year, month, day
```

Optionally you can do the same logic to add hours, minutes, seconds...